# LaTeX p cell width

Tags: tables, width

totally new to LaTeX, this question occured today:

I have a table made of 17 columns. Every column is 0,6cm wide.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0,6cm}}
```

That works perfectly and fine. But i also have on several rows 2 cells which are combined with \multicolumn like this:

```
\multicolumn{2}{|p{1.2cm}|}{\cellcolor{grey}Inverse dependency ratio}
```

Because this multi column combines two differenct cells i figured out 0,6 + 0,6 = 1,2. Right? So i gave this a width of 1,2cm... However this happens:

[image]

The combined \multicolumn doesnt fit to the 2 columns at the bottom of it. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Not taking into account `\tabcolsep` (the distance between the column border and its content.)

Comment: Didnt even know something like that exists... Thanks!

Comment: Also, use `\begin{tabular}{|*{17}{p{0.6cm}|}}
...
\end{tabular}` Writing `p{0.6cm}` 17 times is exhausting and prone to error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make multicolumn width the total of the declared width of each column?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132507/how-to-make-multicolumn-width-the-total-of-the-declared-width-of-each-column)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina it's almost a duplicate but with the extra complication of `|` here. (Although surely that must already be on the site somewhere...)

Answer (score 6):

It is best to post a complete (small) document showing all packages used however..

Aside from the first column, if you look at

```
|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|
```

and want to span those two columns, the first `|` is in the *previous* column so the span should not start with `|` (unless this *is* the first column). Then there is padding of `\tabcolsep`, then column content of `0.6cm`, then another `\tabcolsep`, then `|`. In the original LaTeX `tabular` this took no space, but you used `\cellcolor` so you must have loaded `colortbl` (or `xcolor` which loads `colortbl`) which implies that the `array` package is loaded. In the `array` package tabular `|` takes up the width of the rule `\arrayrulewidth`, then there is `\tabcolsep` padding again, `0.6cm` of content, `\tabcolsep` padding, and another `|` rule .

So you want a

```
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr (0.6cm)*2+1\arrayrulewidth+2\tabcolsep\relax}|}{...}
```

Note this does not have a `|` on the left and includes the space taken up by the padding and rules between the spanned columns.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `0.6cm` instead of `6.5cm` in two different places in your answer?

Comment: I understand what you mean, hoever copying this doesn't help me and only outputs Errors like "Illegal uni of measure (pt inserted)". You forgot\multicolumn{2} to say that 2 cells are combined, but it still doesnt work ...

Comment: @Shiuyin It was late (and you had not provided a test file, which always helps) sorry there was a syntax error, fixed now `(0.6cm)*2` not `2*(0.6cm)` e-tex expression syntax is a little restrictive sometimes:-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the column separation value.

You should try

```
\dimexpr1.6cm+2\tabcolsep
```